# Manage multiple asynchronous operation on XCTests

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, xctest, xctestexpectation

I'm facing with a problem with asynchronous operations in a XCTestCase object.
I started with a chain of `expectation-waitForExpectation`, sometimes passing the expectation instance as a method param to make it fulfilled by the asynchronous operation completion block.
Now I changed the method, because I can't see bad written code as it was before and I tried in this way:

```
- (void)testThatItGoesToTheRightSport
{
  if (! appDelegateInstance.firstTimeLoaded)
  {
     [self __waitForLoadingAppAndDo:^(BOOL launched)
     {
       if (launched)
       {
          [self __goToLiveWithHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success)
            {
              [self __goToLiveSport:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:kDefaultSportCode]
                            handler:^(BOOL success) {
               if (! success)
               {
                 XCTFail(@"Test failed");
               }
             }];
           }
          }];
       }
     }];
  }
  else
  {
    [self __goToLiveWithHandler:^(BOOL success) {
      if (success)
      {
        [self __goToLiveSport:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:kDefaultSportCode]
                      handler:^(BOOL success) {
          if (! success)
          {
            XCTFail(@"Test failed");
          }
        }];
      }
    }];
  }
}
```

With `__waitForLoadingAppAndDo:` method implemented as

```
- (void)__waitForLoadingAppAndDo:(void (^)(BOOL launched))afterBlock
{
  if (! afterBlock)
      XCTFail(@"No afterBlock");

  XCTestExpectation *dataEx = [self expectationForNotification:NOTIFICATION_HOME_LOADED
                                                        object:nil
                                                       handler:^BOOL(NSNotification *notification) {
                                                           [dataEx fulfill];
                                                           return YES;
                                                       }];
  [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:SOCKOPT_TIMEOUT handler:^(NSError *error)
   {
       if (error)
       {
           XCTFail(@"No data received. %@", [error localizedDescription]);
       }
       else
       {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           afterBlock(YES);
         });
       }
   }];
}
```

And the other `__` methods are similar to it. Obviously, now, the `testThat` method is not waiting for the methods completion handler. How can I improve it and how can I make `testThat` methods wait for completion? Is `XCTestExpectation` the way? (tell me not eheh)

**ADDING:** so, is that the unique way?

```
- (void)testThatItGoesToTheRightSport
    {
       if (! appDelegateInstance.firstTimeLoaded)
       {
         XCTestExpectation *waitingLoading = [self expectationWithDescription:@"loadingApp"];
         [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:SOCKOPT_TIMEOUT handler:^(NSError *error) {
           if (error)
           {
             XCTFail(@"After block was not called.");
           }
         }];
         [self __waitForLoadingAppAndDo:^(BOOL launched)
         {
           if (launched)
           {
              [self __goToLiveWithHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if (success)
                {
                  [waitingLoading fulfill];
                  [...]
                }
              }];
           }
          }];
```

**ADDING-2**:

I tried with

```
__block NSError *internalError = nil;
__block XCTestExpectation *finishedTest = [self expectationWithDescription:@"finishedTest"];
dispatch_group_t asyncGroup = dispatch_group_create();

if (! appDelegateInstance.firstTimeLoaded)
{
  dispatch_group_enter(asyncGroup);
  [self __waitForLoadingAppAndDo:^(BOOL launched) {
    if (! launched)
    {
      internalError = [TestUtilities notLoadedAppError];
    }
    dispatch_group_leave(asyncGroup);
  }];

  dispatch_group_enter(asyncGroup);
  [self __goToLiveWithHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (! success)
    {
      internalError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"goLive"
                                          code:-1
                                      userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Errore apertura Live"}];
    }
    dispatch_group_leave(asyncGroup);
  }];

  dispatch_group_notify(asyncGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [finishedTest fulfill];
  });
```

but the groups are called asyncrhonously, without waiting for completion block.
For example: I'm expecting that **OP1** starts first and, in the **OP1** completion block **OP2** will start.

**ADDING-3**:
I used a different approach with `dispatch_semaphore`. I like it, but there is a thing that I would replace. If I will wait for the signal, I'm blocking the main thread, so I have to `dispatch_async` the `wait` command as below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
  dispatch_semaphore_wait(loadedApp, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self __goToLiveWithHandler:^(BOOL success) {
      if (success)
      {
        [...]
      }
    }];
  });
});
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
dispatch_group
```

To create a chain of events.

At the start of your test:

> `Dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();`

Before each async portion call:

```
Dispatch_group_enter(group);
```

And when each async portion has finished use:

```
Dispatch_group_leave(group);
```

(The number of "enter" must equal the number of "leave")

At the end of the async code "wait" :

```
// called when "group" |enter|=|leave|
Dispatch_group_apply(group,main_queue,^{

      // check your conditions....
       If (success) [expectation fulfill];
Else // failure
});

Expectation wait....// add the expectation wait handler as before
```

There are different variations of `dispatch_group` so you may need to tweak according to your use case.

Hope it helps

*******EDIT*******

Per your comment, you may want to nest the groups differently. For instance:

```
// create the expectation
Expectation = ....

dispatch_group_t myGroup = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(myGroup);
// do first portion
dispatch_group_leave(myGroup);

// do the second portion after the first
dispatch_group_apply(myGroup,dispatch_queue..., ^{
   //second code portion

   // chain as many as needed using this technique

   // eventually you will need to fulfill your "expectation
   // ...
   if (success) {
       [expectation fullfil];
   } else {
       XCTAssert(fail,@"The test failed because ....");
   }
});

[self expectation wait...]
```

Comment: I edited the post with the groups method, but it doesn't work. The second op isn't waiting for the first op complete block :S

Comment: I see. If you need the second portion to "wait" for the first portion, than put that code inside of the "dispatch_group_apply" . You can chain your flow any way you need to

Comment: Ok, but it isn't the same thing than put the second operation in the first operation completion block? I don't understand. I want to avoid this chain of block into block into block etc...

Comment: I appended an edit. Hopefully it is clear. dispatch_apply allows performing a code block after all of the "enter" and "leave" have been called. This way you can create async code which is "chainable" (You may want to check "promises" as well)

Comment: Oh it's perfect. Thank you Avner.